# Как привязать событие

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, binding, mvvm

Как привязать событие `UserControls.PreviewMouseDown` к методу во `ViewModel`.
То есть, чтоб при нажатии мышки событие вызывала метод из `ViewModel`.

[Вот](http://nrumyantsev.com/2012/04/01/wpf-4-5-part-6-markup-extensions-for-events/) нашел, но мне нужно это сделать в .NET 4.0

Comment: Используете для мввм какое-либо готовое решение или пишите все с нуля?

Comment: А какое готовое решение?

Comment: Один из вариантов: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для этих целей используется `System.Windows.Interactivity`. Вам нужно подключить [nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) (он доступен и под .NET 4.0), и написать в коде:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnMouse}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <!-- остальной код контрола -->
</UserControl>
```

Это вызовет команду `OnMouse` из вашей VM.

Кроме [`InvokeCommandAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) можно использовать, например, [`CallMethodAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) или [`ChangePropertyAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.changepropertyaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).